# Preventing login from multiple device in yii2 framework

Tags: php, authentication, security, yii2

I am trying to prevent the login from another device. And after all the research i have found using session. I am using the default login system of yii2 framework. And added these codes in the `user` model.
The user model is:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;

//app\models\Users is the model generated using Gii from users table

use app\models\Users as DbUser;

class User extends \yii\base\Object implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface {

public $id;
public $username;
public $password;
public $authKey;
public $token;
public $email;
public $any;
public $user_type;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentity($id) {
    $dbUser = DbUser::find()
            ->where([
                "id" => $id
            ])
            ->one();
    if (!count($dbUser)) {
        return null;
    }
    return new static($dbUser);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $userType = null) {

    $dbUser = DbUser::find()
            ->where(["token" => $token])
            ->one();
    if (!count($dbUser)) {
        return null;
    }
    return new static($dbUser);
}

/**
 * Finds user by username
 *
 * @param  string      $username
 * @return static|null
 */
public static function findByUsername($username) {
    $dbUser = DbUser::find()
            ->where([
                "username" => $username
            ])
            ->one();
    if (!count($dbUser)) 
    {
                    return null;
    }
    return new static($dbUser);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getAuthKey() 
{
    return $this->authKey;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function validateAuthKey($authKey) 
{
    return $this->authKey === $authKey;
}

/**
 * Validates password
 *
 * @param  string  $password password to validate
 * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
 */
public function validatePassword($password)
    {

        return Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
    }



public function session_validate()
    {

        // Encrypt information about this session
        $user_agent = $this->session_hash_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $this->any);

        // Check for instance of session
        if ( session_exists() == false )
        {
            // The session does not exist, create it
             $this->session_reset($user_agent);
        }

        // Match the hashed key in session against the new hashed string
        if ( $this->session_match($user_agent) )
        {
            return true;
        }

        // The hashed string is different, reset session
        $this->session_reset($user_agent);
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * session_exists()
     * Will check if the needed session keys exists.
     *
     * @return {boolean} True if keys exists, else false
     */

    private function session_exists()
    {
        return isset($_SESSION['USER_AGENT_KEY']) && isset($_SESSION['INIT']);
    }

    /**
     * session_match()
     * Compares the session secret with the current generated secret.
     *
     * @param {String} $user_agent The encrypted key
     */

    private function session_match( $user_agent )
    {
        // Validate the agent and initiated
        return $_SESSION['USER_AGENT_KEY'] == $user_agent && $_SESSION['INIT'] == true;
    }

    /**
     * session_encrypt()
     * Generates a unique encrypted string
     *
     * @param {String} $user_agent      The http_user_agent constant
     * @param {String} $unique_string    Something unique for the user (email, etc)
     */

    private function session_hash_string( $user_agent, $unique_string )
    {
        return md5($user_agent.$unique_string);
    }

    /**
     * session_reset()
     * Will regenerate the session_id (the local file) and build a new
     * secret for the user.
     *
     * @param {String} $user_agent
     */

    private function session_reset( $user_agent )
    {
        // Create new id
        session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
        $_SESSION = array();
        $_SESSION['INIT'] = true;

        // Set hashed http user agent
        $_SESSION['USER_AGENT_KEY'] = $user_agent;
    }

    /**
     * Destroys the session
     */

    private function session_destroy()
    {
        // Destroy session
        session_destroy();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**this a better way of doing it is below.**

1. you do is that you add an extra column to your users table, name it 'conc_login' or preferably text because it might be difficult to predict the size of data we are expecting.
2. when the user logs in, check if the logins column is empty, if it is empty, create a json that contains the session_id, time of login using the time() function.
3. If the logins column is not empty or the count of the column when decoded is greater than zero, then you check if the count is greater than login limit , if the number of logins is not yet greater than the login limit, then append the new session to the logins column in the database table
4. If the login limit is reached then check through the logins and check for the one with expired time, for example, a user that is not active of 300secnds is assumed to be logged out, then you delete the session that has expired from the table
5. In any request that is been made by a logged user you check if the session key still exists in the login column of the database ($logins[‘session_key’]), and if it is not found then log the user out immediately to avoid escalation of right and if otherwise then update the $login[‘time’] to the new time().

You can implement this code.

1. Login Form Model Add this function for concurrent user validation

   ```
   $get_limit = Setting::findOne(['name' => 'login_limit']);
   $login_limit = 3; //$get_limit->value;

   $active_sess = User::findOne($getUser->id);

   if ($active_sess->conc_login == '' or count(json_decode($active_sess->conc_login)) == 0) {
       $login_json = json_encode([
           [Yii::$app->session->getId() => Yii::$app->session->getId(), 'session_key' => Yii::$app->session->getId(), 'time' => time()]
       ]);
       $active_sess->conc_login = $login_json;
       $active_sess->save();
   } else if (count(json_decode($active_sess->conc_login)) > 0 and count(json_decode($active_sess->conc_login)) $login_json = json_decode($active_sess->conc_login);
   $login_json[] = [Yii::$app->session->getId() => Yii::$app->session->getId(), 'session_key' => Yii::$app->session->getId(), 'time' => time()];
   $login_json = json_encode($login_json);
   //print_r($login_json); exit;                
   $active_sess->conc_login = $login_json;
   $active_sess->save();
   ```

   } else if (count(json_decode($active_sess->conc_login)) >= $login_limit) {

   ```
   $logins = json_decode($active_sess->conc_login);


   foreach ($logins as $key => $login) {
       if ($login->time < time() - 120) {
           //this checks if the iterated login is greater than the current time -120seconds and if found to be true then the user is inactive
           //then set this current login to null by using the below statement
           //$logins[$key] = null; // or unset($logins[$key]) either should work;
           unset($logins[$key]);
       }
   }

   //after iteration we check if the count of logins is still greater than the limit
   if (count($logins) >= $login_limit) {
       //then return a login error that maximum logins reached
       //echo 'you are not allowed to login as you have breeched the maximum session limit.';
       //exit;
       $login_json = json_encode($logins);
       $active_sess->conc_login = $login_json;
       $active_sess->save();

       $this->addError($attribute, 'you are not allowed to login as you have breeched the maximum session limit.');

   } else {
       //then login is successsfull

       $login_json = [];
       foreach ($logins as $key => $val) {
           $login_json[] = [$val->session_key => $val->session_key, 'session_key' => $val->session_key, 'time' => $val->time];
       }
       $login_json[] = [Yii::$app->session->getId() => Yii::$app->session->getId(), 'session_key' => Yii::$app->session->getId(), 'time' => time()];
       $login_json = json_encode($login_json);

       $active_sess->conc_login = $login_json;
       $active_sess->save();
   }

   //update the logins column to equal to json_encode($logins);
   ```

   }
2. User side update session every 60seconds : SiteController

   ```
   public function actionUserSessionUpdate() {
       $session = Yii::$app->session;
       $userid = $session->get('userid');
       $username = $session->get('username');
       $data = array('session_id' => Yii::$app->session->getId());
       $isUserLogin = (!empty($userid) && !empty($username)) ? 'true' : 'false';
       if ($isUserLogin == 'false') {
           echo 'gotologin'; exit;
           //return $this->redirect(['/login']);
       } else {
           //Login user

       $active_sess = Clientmanagement::findOne($userid);
       $loginjson = json_decode($active_sess->conc_login);

       $login_json = [];
       foreach ($loginjson as $key => $val) {
           if ($val->session_key == Yii::$app->session->getId()) {
               $login_json[] = [$val->session_key => $val->session_key, 'session_key' => $val->session_key, 'time' => time()];
           } else {
               $login_json[] = [$val->session_key => $val->session_key, 'session_key' => $val->session_key, 'time' => $val->time];
           }
       }


       $login_json = json_encode($login_json);
       $active_sess->conc_login = $login_json;
       $active_sess->save();
   }
   exit;


   }
   ```
3. Client ajax

   ```
   <?php
   if (!empty($session->get('userid'))) {

       $usersession_url = Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(["/site/user-session-update"]);

       $scriptb = <<< JS
       $(document).ready(function () {
               //Wait 1 Minutes
          setInterval(function(){ 
                   $.ajax({
                  type:"post",
                  data:'id=session',
                  url:"$usersession_url",
                  success:function(data){

                  }
              });
              }, 60000);  
       });
   JS;
       $this->registerJs($scriptb);
   }
   ?>
   ```
4. UserController Logout

   ```
   public function actionLogout() {
       $session = Yii::$app->session;
       $userid = $session->get('userid');

       //concurrent active user session removed
       $active_sess = Clientmanagement::findOne($userid);
       $loginjson = json_decode($active_sess->conc_login);
       foreach ($loginjson as $key => $login) {
           if ($login->session_key == Yii::$app->session->getId()) {
               unset($loginjson[$key]);
           }
       }
       $login_json = json_encode($loginjson);   

       $active_sess->conc_login = $login_json;
       $active_sess->save();

       $session->destroy();
       return $this->redirect(['/login']);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

We can set that code in component and it will also work for every controller and action. Also, I changed a code

**common/components/LoginDevicesLimit.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\common\components;

use Yii;

/**
 * Logged In Devices Storage Helper
 */
class LoginDevicesLimit extends \yii\base\Component
{
    public function init() {
        $this->saveLoginSession();
        parent::init();
    }

    public function saveLoginSession(){
        $login_limit = env('DEVICES_LIMIT', 3);

        $active_sess = \Yii::$app->user->identityClass::findOne(\Yii::$app->user->id);
        if(!$active_sess){
            return false;
        }

        $session_count = count(json_decode($active_sess->conc_login, true));

        if ($active_sess->conc_login == '' || $session_count == 0) {
            $login_json = json_encode([
                Yii::$app->session->getId() => ['session_key' => Yii::$app->session->getId(), 'time' => time()]
            ]);
            $active_sess->conc_login = $login_json;
            $active_sess->save();
        } else if ($session_count > 0 && $session_count < $login_limit) {
            $login_json = json_decode($active_sess->conc_login, true);
            $login_json[Yii::$app->session->getId()] = ['session_key' => Yii::$app->session->getId(), 'time' => time()];
            $login_json = json_encode($login_json);
            //print_r($login_json); exit;
            $active_sess->conc_login = $login_json;
            $active_sess->save();
        } else if ($session_count > $login_limit) {
            $logins = json_decode($active_sess->conc_login, true);

            foreach ($logins as $key => $login) {
                if ($login->time < time() - 120) {
                    //this checks if the iterated login is greater than the current time -120seconds and if found to be true then the user is inactive
                    //then set this current login to null by using the below statement
                    //$logins[$key] = null; // or unset($logins[$key]) either should work;
                    unset($logins[$key]);
                }
            }

            //after iteration we check if the count of logins is still greater than the limit
            if (count($logins) > $login_limit) {
                //then return a login error that maximum logins reached
                //echo 'you are not allowed to login as you have breeched the maximum session limit.';
                //exit;
                $login_json = json_encode($logins);
                $active_sess->conc_login = $login_json;
                $active_sess->save();

                throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'You are not allowed to login as you have reached the maximum session limit.');

            } else {
                //then login is successsfull

                $login_json = [];
                foreach ($logins as $key => $val) {
                    $login_json[] = [$val->session_key => $val->session_key, 'session_key' => $val->session_key, 'time' => $val->time];
                }
                $login_json[] = [Yii::$app->session->getId() => Yii::$app->session->getId(), 'session_key' => Yii::$app->session->getId(), 'time' => time()];
                $login_json = json_encode($login_json);

                $active_sess->conc_login = $login_json;
                $active_sess->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate additional authentication code during login process that will be stored in user's identity and saved in db as well. Every time user invokes action his code is compared to this saved in db and if doesn't match user is forcefully logged out . This way only the latest login is valid.  refer this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/68035-preventing-multiple-computers-connecting-to-one-same-account/%22link%22)

Comment: i am trying to prevent the login from another, not already logged in one to forcefully logout.

Comment: the same can be applied. the first time you log in , set a session key to active in DB. Everytime the login procedure is invoked, check the status of the session key. If a session key is active, then deny login from 2nd device

Comment: this gives the problem when i not logout and close the browser manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way to prevent the login from another device.

You need to configure your application as shown below using the [webvimark/user-management](https://github.com/webvimark/user-management) library.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`auth_key` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`password_hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`confirmation_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`superadmin` smallint(1) DEFAULT '0',
`created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
`updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
`registration_ip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`bind_to_ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
`email_confirmed` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`sessions` longtext,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

```php
<?php
$config =
    [
        'bootstrap' => ['log', 'LogoutDevices'],
        'components' =>
            [
                'user' => ['class' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\components\UserConfig', 'enableAutoLogin' => true, 'on afterLogin' => function($event) {(new \app\components\ABCDEFG\DevicesLimit\LoginDevicesLimit())->sessionManager(); \webvimark\modules\UserManagement\models\UserVisitLog::newVisitor($event->identity->id);}],
                'LogoutDevices' => ['class' => 'app\components\ABCDEFG\DevicesLimit\LogoutDevices']
            ]
    ]
```

Then, you need to use the classes below:

```php
<?php
namespace app\models\UserManagement;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property    string  $sessions
 */
class User extends \webvimark\modules\UserManagement\models\User
{
    function __construct($config = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
namespace app\components\ABCDEFG\DevicesLimit;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;
use app\models\UserManagement\User;

/**
 * Logged In Devices Storage Helper
 *
 * Class LoginDevicesLimit
 * @package app\components\ABCDEFG\DevicesLimit
 *
 * @property    integer $iDevicesLimit
 *
 */
class LoginDevicesLimit extends Component
{
    private  int $iDevicesLimit = 1;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function getDevicesLimit() : int
    {
        return $this->iDevicesLimit;
    }

    public function setDevicesLimit(int $iDevicesLimit = 1) : self
    {
        if($iDevicesLimit >= 1)
        {
            $this->iDevicesLimit = $iDevicesLimit;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function sessionManager() : self
    {
        if(isset(Yii::$app->user->id))
        {
            $oUser = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);

            if(!empty($oUser))
            {
                if(User::hasRole('Expert', $superAdminAllowed = false))
                {
                    $this->setDevicesLimit(3);
                }

                $sSessionsJSON = $oUser->sessions;

                $aSessions = json_decode($sSessionsJSON, true);

                $aSession = Helper::getCurrentSessionData();

                if(is_array($aSessions) && !empty($aSessions))
                {
                    $bIsSessionExists = false;

                    foreach($aSessions as $iSessionKey => $aSessionData)
                    {
                        if($aSessionData['id'] == $aSession['id'])
                        {
                            $aSessions[$iSessionKey] = $aSession;

                            $bIsSessionExists = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if($bIsSessionExists == true)
                    {
                        $aTime = array_column($aSessions, 'time');

                        array_multisort
                        (
                            $aTime, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC,
                            $aSessions
                        );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        array_unshift($aSessions, $aSession);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $aSessions[] = $aSession;
                }

                $aSessions = array_slice($aSessions, 0, $this->getDevicesLimit());

                $sSessionsJSON = json_encode($aSessions);
                if(json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE)
                {
                    $oUser->sessions = $sSessionsJSON;
                    $oUser->save();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
namespace app\components\ABCDEFG\DevicesLimit;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;

use app\models\UserManagement\User;

/**
 * Logged In Devices Storage Helper
 *
 * Class LogoutDevices
 * @package app\components\ABCDEFG\DevicesLimit
 *
 */
class LogoutDevices extends Component
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        self::logoutOnExceedingLimit();
    }

    public static function logoutOnExceedingLimit()
    {
        $xRetValue = NULL;

        if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax == false && isset(Yii::$app->user->id))
        {
            $oUser = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);

            if(!empty($oUser))
            {
                $sSessionsJSON = $oUser->sessions;

                $aSessions = json_decode($sSessionsJSON, true);

                $aSession = Helper::getCurrentSessionData();

                if(is_array($aSessions) && !empty($aSessions))
                {
                    $bIsSessionExists = in_array($aSession['id'], array_column($aSessions, 'id'));

                    if($bIsSessionExists == false)
                    {
                        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('devices-limit', true);
                        Yii::$app->session->close();
                        Yii::$app->user->logout(false);
                        $xRetValue = Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/devices-limit-reached'], 302);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $xRetValue;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
namespace app\components\ABCDEFG\DevicesLimit;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;

/**
 * Helper
 *
 * Class Helper
 * @package app\components\ABCDEFG\DevicesLimit
 *
 */
class Helper extends Component
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public static function getCurrentSessionData() : array
    {
        return
            [
                'id'        => Yii::$app->session->getId(),
                'time'      => time(),
                'device'    => Yii::$app->request->userAgent,
            ];
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).